# Parsing xml with a tag that contains more than one information

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have an xml like this

```
<catalogo>
<items>
<item>
<ID>1</ID>
<NAME>VA</NAME>
<SIZE>S</SIZE>
<GROUP>1,2,3,4</GROUP>
</item>
<item>
<ID>2</ID>
<NAME>VA</NAME>
<SIZE>M</SIZE>
<GROUP>l,2,3,4</GROUP>
</item>
<item>
<ID>3</ID>
<NAME>VA</NAME>
<SIZE>L</SIZE>
<GROUP>1,2,3,4</GROUP>
</item>
<item>
<ID>2</ID>
<NAME>VA</NAME>
<SIZE>XL</SIZE>
<GROUP>l,2,3,4</GROUP>
</item>
</items>
</catalogo>
```

The TAG GROUP it refers to all id of the products that are the same but differs in the value of the TAG SIZE.

I'd like to obtain a sql table like this

```
  id name size1 size2 size3 size4
   1   va   s      m     l     xl
```

How can I parse this xml with php to obtain my desired table?

Comment: as with anything to do with reading xml: http://php.net/dom

Comment: Hi Marc thanks...but I now how to parse it just to retrieve data from xml...but I don't know how put the value of size in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you get the XML and cannot change it:

(1) read the XML, build array `$c`, assuming `<NAME>` as linking the `<SIZE>s`.
the code will generate an associative array with key = `<NAME>` and value = `<SIZE>s` seperated by |: `["VA"] => string(9) "|S|M|L|XL"`

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);
$c = array();

foreach ($xml->items->item as $item) {

 $n = (string)$item->NAME;
 if (!isset($c[$n])) $c[$n]='';
 $c[$n] .= "|". (string)$item->SIZE;

}
```

(2) writing `$c` to a table (database-table?, HTML-table? you decide...):

```
foreach ($c as $name => $sizes) {

    $size = explode('|', trim($sizes,'|'));
$max = count($size);
// enter code for whatsoever table...
    // echo for demonstration:
    echo "--$name:-----<br />";
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) echo "size$i: {$size[$i]}<br />";

}
```

see live-demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VL1hgw

SIn case you **MAKE** the XML yourself, make it **differently**, like...

```
<item id="1">
    <name>VA</name>
    <size>S</size>
    <size>M</size>
    <size>L</size>
    <size>XL</size>
</item>
```

Comment: hi michi thanks a lot...you're genious!i don't understand where put my code sql in your formula....suppose that my table name is "friend" and i'd like to insert only the value of size and the id. Thanks

Comment: I tried to use thi code where you wrote "// enter code for whatsoever table..." 
$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('$name','$size[0]','$size[1]','$size[2]','$size[3]')";
$rssql = mysql_query($sql);

but it doesn't work...where I fault?

Comment: @user2120473: mysql_-functions are deprecated, please use mysqli_ or PDO, see php.net for basics. Try it, then, if you need help, open a new question on SO! Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your work,...it works fine...it was a stupid mine error...I'd like to know if is possible the ID of the object in the result both with name...for example id =1 name= VA size = X|M|etc....

Comment: @user2120473: try it, if you need help, open a new question and show what you want / what you've tried! Good luck!